# Call of function of a database from the java-program

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, sql-function

There is a Postgresql database with the following function cap

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION net_train(terms text[], answer integer)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$begin
--this code is stub
end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION net_train(text[], integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

It is necessary to call this function from java program. Tell me how to do it (preferably with sample code).

Comment: It's as simple as running `select net_trains(..)` through JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC PostgreSQL doc contains [this page](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html), which details how to call a function using [Connection.prepareCall()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29). It returns a [CallableStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)

> The interface used to execute SQL stored procedures. The JDBC API
>   provides a stored procedure SQL escape syntax that allows stored
>   procedures to be called in a standard way for all RDBMSs. This escape
>   syntax has one form that includes a result parameter and one that does
>   not. If used, the result parameter must be registered as an OUT
>   parameter. The other parameters can be used for input, output or both.
>   Parameters are referred to sequentially, by number, with the first
>   parameter being 1.